# Get the list of packages that are not installed on a Debian system

Tags: debian, shell-script

I am writing a script to print the list of packages which are not installed.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a LIST_OF_PACKAGES=("php5" "nginx")

for i in "${LIST_OF_PACKAGES[@]}"
do
        PACKAGE_STATUS=`dpkg-query -W -f='${Status} ${Version}\n' $i | grep --line-buffered -v "install ok"`
        ECHO=`echo $i * $PACKAGE_STATUS * $i`
done
```

I am trying to include these below lines in for loop:

```
echo $ECHO | awk -F "*" '{print $1}' | sed '/^\s*$/d'
```

Basically, I am trying to grep the packages which are not installed. so I am cropping the list based on  "*" .

Current Output:

```
unknown ok not-installed
```

Required Output:

```
nginx * unknown ok not-installed
```

I want to ignore the packages that are installed.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Unix & Linux! I submitted an edit to make the title of your question point more directly at your problem.

Comment: Because your `*` is not quoted or escaped, it will expand into all the files in your current directory. use `status="$i * $PACKAGE_STATUS * $i"` and then later, make sure that is quoted: `echo "$status"`

Comment: @glennjackman I changed to "?" for clear differentiation.  However, I am still not sure how to fetch only data other than installed packages

Comment: `?` is still a shell wildcard, and will match a filename that is only one character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the not installed packages directly with aptitude:

```
aptitude search "!(~i)"
```

You can also use the more explicit but equivalent form:

```
aptitude search "?not(?installed)"
```

If you want to print only the package names, you can add a format option:

```
 aptitude -F "%p" search "?not(?installed)"
```

Read the [Search term reference from aptitude](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html#searchTermName), it's useful.